# PySimpleGUI Monospace font

Tags: python, pysimplegui

How can I create a Multiline in PySimpleGUI which uses a monospaced font?

```py
sg.Multiline(
 "Test",
 expand_x=True,
 expand_y=True,
 key="-TEXT-",
 background_color="black",
 text_color="white",
 no_scrollbar=True
)
```

I have this element and I tried to change the font with

```py
font=("Andale Mono", 12)
```

to monospace but it isn't monospaced.

Comment: Do you have the font "Andale Mono" installed? Are you sure it's monospaced?

Comment: Yes, I have it installed and it‘s monospaced

Comment: Edit: It worked, but I don’t know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use option `font` when initiate Elements, function `sg.set_options` or `Window` class.

Be sure to confirm the font "Andale Mono" exist in the list `sg.Text.fonts_installed_list()` before you use it.

```py
import string
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font1 = ("Andale Mono", 20)
font2 = ("Courier New", 20)
font3 = ("Arial", 20, 'bold italic')

sg.set_options(font=font3)

layout = [
    [sg.Multiline(string.ascii_lowercase, size=(40, 1), font=font1)],
    [sg.Multiline(string.ascii_lowercase, size=(40, 1), font=font2)],
    [sg.Multiline(string.ascii_lowercase, size=(40, 1))],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
print("Andale Mono" in sg.Text.fonts_installed_list())
window.read(close=True)
```

[image]

Cases for font, including font family and font size

- If not specified or `None` in PySimpleGUI, `sg.DEFAULT_FONT` will be used.
- If specified, font exists in tkinter, then use it.
- If specified, font not exists in tkinter, then `tkinter.font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")` will be used, use the size even if wrong font family specified and also size specified.

In your case, it is most possible that "Andale Mono" not installed in your system/platform, so another default font used for it.